# JavaScript function menu toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone hope you are all well, just wondering if someone could give me hand I have a nav bar that when screen is max-width 750px the nav links turn into toogle menu. My problem is I can't seem to get the toggle menu to open and close when I click on it,I have googled and tried a few different code sorces with no luck.
Any help will be very appreciated.

This is my current code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("menu-toggle").on("click", function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('showing');
    $('.nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
  });
});
```

```css
header .menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}


/***** MEDIA QUERIES*****/

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  header {
    position: relative;
  }
  header ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: #666666;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .showing {
    max-height: 100em;
  }
  header ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  header ul li ul {
    position: static;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header ul li ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #666666;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
  header ul li ul li a.logout {
    color: #ff0000;
  }
  header .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.9em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
    awesome.min.css">

<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-align-justify menu-toggle"></i>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="#">Login</a></li> -->
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Nathan Ashbury
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="logout">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Please learn the name of the language you're writing code in.

Comment: $('.nav') instead of $('nav'). In the function you're calling, this might be a typo.

Comment: You are missing `.` here `$("menu-toggle")` as well .

Comment: Use it code - `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-toggle").on("click", function() {
    $('header ul').toggleClass('showing');
  });
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the jquery .menu-toggle to toggle onclick() function

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".menu-toggle").on("click", function () {
            $('.nav').toggleClass('showing');
            $('.nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
      });
  });
```

Comment: omg thank you so much feel so stupid not to have picked that up myself

Answer (score 0):

Your **nav** is a class, use `$('.nav')`.
You have not written CSS for the class name `.showing` for `.nav` or `.nav ul`. So, nothing will happen even if you click.